# Show that a given Eigenvalue belongs to Matrix without characteristic equation

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that the given a eigenvalue $λ=1$ is an eigenvalue to matrix
$$ T=\begin{bmatrix}-11 &9& 6\\ -8& 6& 2\\ -6& 6& 7\end{bmatrix}$$

WITHOUT using the characteristic equation... I have NO clue, please help with this :)

Comment: One possible route is to hit it with an arbitrary vector (a, b, c) and after multiplying you can make a system of three equations to find the corresponding eigenvector. There may be easier ways, though.

Comment: Hint: The definition of an Eigenvalue $\lambda$ is for a matrix $A$, there exists an exists an eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $A\mathbf{v}=\lambda\mathbf{v}$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the matrix 
$$ T - \lambda = T- 1 = \begin{pmatrix} -12 & 9 & 6 \\ -8 & 5 & 2 \\ -6 & 6 & 6 \end{pmatrix} $$
Now transform it to row echelon form to get 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} -12 & 9 & 6 \\ 0 & -1 & -2 \\ 0 & \frac 32 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \leadsto \begin{pmatrix} -12 & 9 & 6 \\ 0 & -1 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
As $T-1$ has rank $2$, $\dim\ker (T- 1) = 1$ and $\lambda = 1$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: In particular, one may then compute that $v = (-1,-2,1)$ is the associated eigenvector.  In order to show that $1$ is an eigenvector, it suffices to compute $Tv = v$.

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't that count as using the equation, just not writing it out? What would you say?

Comment: @TeaClub the characteristic equation uses a determinant, which wasn't used here

Comment: Aha! Thanx, just thought (A-λI)=0 was characteristic equation, but now it makes more sense :) Thx a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Write $$T-I=\pmatrix{-12&9&6\\-8 &5 & 2 \\ -6&6&6}$$
Suppose $\bf{v}=\pmatrix{a \\ b \\ c}$ satisfies $(T-I)\bf{v}=0$ (equivalently, $T\bf{v}=\bf{v}$). Then by the third component, $a=b+c$, and by the first component $12a=9b+6c$ (or $4a=3b+2c$). So $4b+4c=3b+2c$, that is $b=-2c$, and $a=-c$. So $\bf{v}=$$-c\pmatrix{1 \\ 2 \\ -1}$. Since $-8+2\cdot 5-2=0$, it follows that $\pmatrix{1 \\ 2 \\ -1}$ (or any non-zero multiple of it) is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $1$. In particular, $1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Comment: I like this way, feels like you have a very deep understanding of this, deeper than mine anyway haha! But just for clarification, why is v*R2=0 next step to take, is v an Eigenvector for T? And if so, why does it make sense to multiply them, why the row?

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry, I don't understand - what does v*R2 mean? For what it's worth this is essentially what user247327 suggested, with the details fleshed out.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use the **definition** of eigenvalue!

$\lambda= 1$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $\begin{bmatrix}-11 & 9 & 6 \\ -8 & 6 & 2 \\ -6 & 6 & 7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$.  DO the matrix multiplication on the left and then solve the resulting equations for x, y, and z.  As long as they are not all 0, this is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Haha, smart one :) I guess thats what my professor was looking for